# What draws the Constraint menu completely?

Tags: python, interface

I am working on recreating the UI for displaying constraints inside the tool shelf. What does not work is listing the added constraint values.
[image]

Below is the code I wrote based on what I found inside the constraint py file.

```
# CONSTRAINTS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Constratints(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Constratints"
    bl_idname = "Constratints"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Modeling Toolbox"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object and context.object.data

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
  #      con = DATA_PT_constraints(context)
        ob = context.object

        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()

        row.operator_menu_enum("object.constraint_add", "type", text="Add Object Constraint")
        for con in ob.constraints:
            box = layout.template_constraint(con)
            if box:
                getattr(self, con.type)(context, box, con)          

#        for con in obj.constraints:
#            self.draw_constraint(context, con)
```

This is the code I used to create this for modifiers:

```
# MODIFIER ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ObjectModifier(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Modifiers"
    bl_idname = "ObjectModifier"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Modeling Toolbox"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object and context.object.data

    def draw(self, context):
        mp = DATA_PT_modifiers(context)
        ob = context.object

        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()

        row.operator_menu_enum("object.modifier_add", "type")
        row.operator("object.make_links_data", text="Copy Modifiers From").type="MODIFIERS"
        for md in ob.modifiers:
            box = layout.template_modifier(md)
            if box:
                getattr(mp, md.type)(box, ob, md)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code in  `startup/bl_ui/properties_constraints.py` .
ConstraintsButtonsPanel class has a draw method defined for each constraint type, for example `TRACK_TO`

```
class ConstraintButtonsPanel:
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "constraint"

    # .... 
    def TRACK_TO(self, context, layout, con):
        self.target_template(layout, con)

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="To:")
        row.prop(con, "track_axis", expand=True)

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(con, "up_axis", text="Up")
        row.prop(con, "use_target_z")

        self.space_template(layout, con)

#....
class OBJECT_PT_constraints(ConstraintButtonsPanel, Panel):
```

Notice the `OBJECT_PT_constraints` class inherits the `ConstraintButtonsPanel` class, giving it all the attributes defined therein.

`ConstraintsButtonsPanel.TRACK_TO` is the layout code for a track-to constraint, without this, the line (when `con.type == 'TRACK_TO'`)

```
getattr(self, con.type)(context, box, con)
```

will result in the error

```
AttributeError: 'Constratints' object has no attribute 'TRACK_TO'
```

A quick fix would be to import the `ConstraintsButtonsPanel` class and use it in the `getattr(...)` call, like so

```
import bpy

from bl_ui.properties_constraint import ConstraintButtonsPanel

class Constratints(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Constratints"
    bl_idname = "Constratints"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Modeling Toolbox"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object and context.object.data

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
  #      con = DATA_PT_constraints(context)
        ob = context.object

        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()

        row.operator_menu_enum("object.constraint_add", "type", text="Add Object Constraint")
        for con in ob.constraints:
            box = layout.template_constraint(con)
            if box:
                getattr(ConstraintButtonsPanel, con.type)(ConstraintButtonsPanel, context, box, con)    
                #getattr(self, con.type)(context, box, con)

bpy.utils.register_class(Constratints)
```

Comment: I had a hunch this might be the case but I did not fully understand everything when I read the py file. Thank you for clearing this up. As it seems this is done differently than the modifier stack. BTW what is the purpose of "bpy.utils.register_class(Constratints)"? This should be at the end of my script file when registering unregistering? Your code adjustments work also without this line - so I am curious.

Comment: Panel and Operator classes need to be registered for blender to recognise them.  For addons the code should be in the register method (unregister code in unregister method).  When running from text editor you will often see the code `if __name__ == '__main__": register()` which will register the classes when running the code from the text editor.  The line as shown was from a test file and I prob should have either not included or set it up properly.   Also all pertinent classes can be registered in one fell swoop using `bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)`.  I prefer to register each class.

Comment: Ah good, I have the register / unregister code in my add-on.